# accessing a vector in a function

Tags: qt, vector, reference

I'm quite new to c++ and am not very good at understanding about references and pointers.
I'm making a project in Qt to book appointments in a salon and am currently trying to assign a stylist object to the stylist data member in the chair object.
The function below is to assign stylist to a particular chair. At the end of this function, if you print out the stylist name of the stylist in the chair it has been assigned, however outside of this function the value is not assigned. All the getters are returning a reference but the Calender vector, a vector of Week objects, is just called as it is a data member of the class holders. I am wondering if this is the issue but I thought using the [] operator meant that the vector value at that index was returned by reference.

```
void Holders::BookStylistToChair(int week, int day, float timeslot, stylist temp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Calender[week].getaweek()[day].getaday()[timeslot].GetNumberOfChairsInslot(); i++) {
        bool check = Calender[week].getaweek()[day].getaday()[timeslot].GetChairVector()[i].getoccupied();
        if (check == false) {
            Calender[week].getaweek()[day].getaday()[timeslot].GetChairVector()[i].SetStylist(temp);
            Calender[week].getaweek()[day].getaday()[timeslot].GetChairVector()[i].Setoccupied();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Week class is shown below:

```
class Week {
private:
    //A week full of 7 days
    QVector<Day> AWeek;
public:
    //CREATE DAYS IN A WEEK
    void Create7days(int, int, int);
    //Getter
    QVector<Day>& getaweek() ;
};
```

The week class contains a getter getaweek, which returns a vector of objects of class day. Day contains

```
class Day {
private:
    QString DayName;
    // A day full of timeslots
    QVector<Timeslot> ADay;
public:
    //Create Timeslots
    void CreateTimeSlot(int, int, int);
    void setdayname(QString);
    //Getter
    QString getdayname();
    QVector<Timeslot>& getaday() ;
};
```

The getters are all returning references but I'm unsure if they are correct because I haven't used const even though I know I probably should but I keep getting errors when I do I'm not sure how to include const references.
I hope this is enough information I'm sorry if it isn't.
Thank you

Comment: How `Calender` class looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Calender is a vector, of type Week. I had Caledner as a class before sorry. But now it is a vector of type weekclass Week {
private:
    //A week full of 7 days
    QVector<Day> AWeek;
public:
    //CREATE DAYS IN A WEEK
    void Create7days(int, int, int);
    //Getter
    QVector<Day>& getaweek() ;
}; 
  
the week class contains the getter get a week, which returns a vector of days

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information.

Comment: sorry, have updated it now